# downloaded image is display but hosting server saved image cannot be displayed in android

Tags: android, mysql, android-glide

I have create an application in android. In my hosting server there are two types of image paths stored, one is downloaded from google and another is a created folder of my domain. When accessing all the images, all downloaded images are shown but saved images can't be seen in my android app.

This is my Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//this is the JSON Data URL
//make sure you are using the correct ip else it will not work
private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://mdconstructionpune.com/AndriodPHP/Api.php";

//a list to store all the products
List<Product> productList;

//the recyclerview
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //getting the recyclerview from xml
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //initializing the productlist
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    //this method will fetch and parse json
    //to display it in recyclerview
    loadProducts();
}

private void loadProducts() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            productList.add(new Product(
                                    product.getInt("id"),
                                    product.getString("title"),
                                    product.getString("shortdesc"),
                                    product.getDouble("rating"),
                                    product.getDouble("price"),
                                    product.getString("image")
                            ));
                        }

                        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    //adding our stringrequest to queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

my adapter class is

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

private Context mCtx;
private List<Product> productList;

public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.productList = productList;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, null);
    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Product product = productList.get(position);

    //loading the image
    Glide.with(mCtx)
            .load(product.getImage())
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
    holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());
    holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getRating()));
    holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewRating, textViewPrice;
    ImageView imageView;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
        textViewRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
        textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

and model class is

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String shortdesc;
    private double rating;
    private double price;
    private String image;

    public Product(int id, String title, String shortdesc, double rating, double price, String image) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.shortdesc = shortdesc;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getShortdesc() {
        return shortdesc;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: any help is appreciated...

Comment: share your full code.

Comment: i shared my all code it is just copy paste but when i access images from database then it see blank in my RecyclerView so how to show these images in my app

Answer (score 0):

Product Model Class

```
public class Product {

    private String image;

    public Product(String id) {
        id = image;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Main Activity Class

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        Product product;
        List<Product> productList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Application.getInstance().initAppLanguage(this);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


            productList = new ArrayList<>();


            loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://mdconstructionpune.com/AndriodPHP/Api.php",
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.d("Responce",response);
                            try {
                                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject product1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String id = product1.getString("image");
                                    product = new Product(id);
                                    product.setImage(id);
                                    productList.add(product);

                                }

                                ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    });

            //adding our stringrequest to queue
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        }
```

Adapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Product> productList;

    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        //loading the image
        Glide.with(mCtx)
                .load(product.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);

     /*   holder.textViewTitle.setText(product.getTitle());
        holder.textViewShortDesc.setText(product.getShortdesc());
        holder.textViewRating.setText(String.valueOf(product.getRating()));
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewTitle, textViewShortDesc, textViewRating, textViewPrice;
        ImageView imageView;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

           /* textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            textViewShortDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShortDesc);
            textViewRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewRating);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrice);*/
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this code and fetch image its works

Comment: hii mayur i run your code but it gives me below error.

Comment: W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for image